# How to install the easyconnect client in the Manjaro system?

Tags: linux, installation, manjaro

## problem

### method 1

I was trying to install easyconnect in Manjaro, using commands:

```bash
yay -S easyconnect
```

but I got the error messages:

```bash
==> Validating source files with md5sums...
    EasyConnect_x64_7_6_7_3.deb ... FAILED
    pango-1.42.4.tar.xz ... Passed
==> ERROR: One or more files did not pass the validity check!
 -> error downloading sources: easyconnect 
         context: exit status 1
```

### method 2

And I tried another way, using commands:

```bash
debtap -q EasyConnect_x64_7_6_7_3.deb
sudo pacman -U easyconnect-7.6.7.7-1-x86_64.pkg.tar.zst  # generated by the command above
```

but when I tried to run it, there was no response:

```bash
cd /usr/share/sangfor/EasyConnect
./EasyConnect
```

Could you please help me solve this problem? Thanks a lot!

## local environment

- OS: Manjaro Linux
- OS Version: 21.3.4
- KDE Plasma Version: 5.24.6
- KDE Frameworks Version: 5.96.0
- Kernel Version: 5.15.55-1-MANJARO (64-bit)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From method 1, we can know that the `md5sum` in the `PKGBUILD` is not the same as the one from the `EasyConnect_x64_7_6_7_3.deb` file.
So, I updated the md5sum first by running commands below inside the folder`/usr/share/sangfor/EasyConnect`:

```bash
updpkgsums
```

then I ran the following commands again:

```bash
makepkg
......
```